# Silex file input with FormBuilderInterface

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony-forms, silex

After a very fresh subscribing, I've decided to ask for help here, the place where I found so many solutions to my problems in the past.

I just achieved a course on Openclassrooms (Evolve to a professionnal PHP architecture) giving the keys to start with Silex, Twig and Bootstrap, and am reading Silex's documentation while making a website.

But in all this dev, I decide to use the `FormBuilderInterface` and add a file input to my form :

```
class ActivityType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title', 'text')
            ->add('public', 'choice', array(
                'choices' => array(
                    'children' => 'children',
                    'adults' => 'adults',
                    'family' => 'family',
                    ),
                ))
            ->add('withHorses', 'choice', array(
                'expanded' => 'true',
                'label' => 'With horses',
                ))
            ->add('content', 'textarea')
            ->add('image', 'file', array(
                'required' => 'false',
                'data_class' => null,
                ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'activity';
    }
}
```

`data_class` => `null` is there to avoid an exception.

Here's the view :

```
{{ form_start(activityForm, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-horizontal'} }) }}
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form_label(activityForm.title, null, { 'label_attr':  {
            'class': 'col-sm-4 control-label'
        }}) }}
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            {{ form_errors(activityForm.title) }}
            {{ form_widget(activityForm.title, { 'attr':  {
                'class': 'form-control'
            }}) }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form_label(activityForm.public, null, { 'label_attr':  {
            'class': 'col-sm-4 control-label'
        }}) }}
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            {{ form_errors(activityForm.public) }}
            {{ form_widget(activityForm.public, { 'attr':  {
                'class': 'form-control'
            }}) }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form_label(activityForm.withHorses, null, { 'label_attr':  {
            'class': 'col-sm-4 control-label'
        }}) }}
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            {{ form_errors(activityForm.withHorses) }}
            {{ form_widget(activityForm.withHorses, { 'attr':  {
                'class': 'form-control'
            }}) }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form_label(activityForm.content, null, { 'label_attr':  {
            'class': 'col-sm-4 control-label'
        }}) }}
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            {{ form_errors(activityForm.content) }}
            {{ form_widget(activityForm.content, { 'attr':  {
                'class': 'form-control',
                'rows': '8'
            }}) }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form_label(activityForm.image, null, { 'label_attr':  {
            'class': 'col-sm-4 control-label'
        }}) }}
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            {{ form_errors(activityForm.image) }}
            {{ form_widget(activityForm.image, { 'attr':  {
                'class': 'form-control',
                'accept': 'image/*'
            }}) }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-3">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" />
        </div>
    </div>
{{ form_end(activityForm) }}
```

The file input is displayed but [here](http://prntscr.com/8vjljm) is what it looks like.

While examining the DOM, I see something weird [here](http://prntscr.com/8v9tnl). The `div` containing the file input does not possess the `class "form-group`" and I also figure that the attributes added to the input from the view (`class: form-control` and accept: images/*) are not taken in consideration.

I spent hours on the doc and have done some Google researchs and no result. I admit I have some difficulties with completely understanding Silex and I am perplex regarding this situation. I would like this file input to be normally positioned between the text-area and the submit button, also the label and the file input to be horizontally aligned, and that this part of the form takes in consideration the code from the view (classes and attributes).

Also, if anybody has infos on `data_class`, I would be very interested (especially why it has to be null to avoid an exception with a file input when using that interface).

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind !

The bug was behind the chair and the desk ! The form I showed you was correct from the beginning, I just mistook the files and was looking at the wrong one. Oh and for the people who want to reuse my code : be careful because withHorses is supposed to be a checkbox.

So you need to change :

`add('withHorses', 'choice', array(
                'expanded' => 'true',
                'label' => 'With horses',
                ))`

into :

`add('withHorses', 'checkbox', array(
                'label' => 'With horses',
                ))`

[info here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/checkbox.html#value)

Thegeekrv, with the FormBuilderInterface, I get a nice view in the bootstrap style so I don't think I really need BraincraftedBootstrap.
However, the file input's style isn't nice so I chose to use [bootstrap-filestyle](http://markusslima.github.io/bootstrap-filestyle/). [This is what it looks like, here.](http://prntscr.com/8wl8ii)

Thanks a lot for you help and your corrections !

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would be using BraincraftedBootstrap : https://mrgierer.wordpress.com/2014/02/16/bootstrap-themed-forms-with-silex/

It does everything you are doing, but it works :)

Comment: Thank you ! I've been trying to use it but I still have some difficulties understanding everything, espacially the part with `{% form_theme activityForm 'bootstrap.html.twig' %}`. I don't really know where to put it in the view, nor what it means exactly.

Comment: What kind of difficulties?

Comment: General difficulties. I've been used to understand everything in my code and since I've been using Silex, I feel uneasy because I feel like using the services, share, Twig and so on without understanding how they work in details. So when I meet a bug, most of the time, I'm completely lost. And even when I spend hours on the documentation, I get more and more lost. But that's very general; that's why, in that case especially, I gave the example of `{% form_theme activityForm 'bootstrap.html.twig' %}` so you have a concrete case.